# Big-Calander Events not loading in custom view

Tags: reactjs, momentjs, react-big-calendar

I've mixed a couple of examples (CustomView, Moment JS localization) in order to create a view that only shows each Wednesday and Thursday. However, the events are not displayed.

The events are transferred from the parent to the child component (including the Calendar component). However, simply hardcoding events also does not work.

I feel like it's a problem within the custom view, but I cannot find what exactly.

See [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-big-calendar-example-forked-xgdh64?file=/src/App.js).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing I notice, looking at your codesandbox, is that you forgot to include the stylesheet. This is mentioned in the [Getting Started](http://jquense.github.io/react-big-calendar/examples/index.html?path=/docs/about-big-calendar--page) section of the documentation. Your `min` and `max` props are being passed `moment` objects, rather than true js `Date` objects. And the hardcoded event date you included wasn't in the displayed date range.

Comment: Here's a fork of your [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-big-calendar-example-forked-cp8pvh?file=/src/App.js)